# vertical aligning

Tags: vertical-alignment, ytableau

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{genyoungtabtikz}
\usepackage{ytableau}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\begin{document}
\begin{example}
Let $\tau=\Yboxdim{16pt}\young(7241,63,5)$ and $\upsilon=\Yboxdim{16pt}\young(1247,36,5)$ be tableaux. Then we have the 
following equation of tabloids:
\[\{\tau\}=\{\upsilon\}=\ytableausetup{tabloids,centertableaux}\ytableaushort{1247,36,5}.\]
\label{tabloid}
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

In the above code the first two tables (which we call tableaux) are drawn after the \tau = and the \upsilon =. Then there is a table (called tabloid) drawn with {\tau}={\upsilon}=...

The last one has the = sign vertically centred to the tabloid which is what I want. Whereas the tableaux above don't have = signs aligned that way.

I am not geeky enough to resolve the issue, nor is this question easy to google.

I downloaded the ytableau.sty and `\usepackage`-d it to be able to draw these.

Here is a picture:

[image: Tableau example]

Comment: `young` is somewhat deprecated. Consider `youngtab` or `ytableau` instead.

Comment: Oh sorry it should be ytableau, I'll edit it

Comment: help us to help you! please extend your code snippet to complete small compilable document.

Comment: Consider putting `\ytableausetup{tabloids,centertableaux}` to the preamble.

Comment: @Zarko, done. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @JouleV, thank you, but unfortunately didn't work even on moving to preamble.

Comment: I added the 'ytableau' tag. Feel free to revert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\Yvcentermath1`.

I've found `genyoungtabtikz` package and its documentation [here](http://www.maths.q[mul.ac.uk/~mf/genyoungtabtikz.html) (the package is not present in TeX Live 2018 distribution).

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{genyoungtabtikz}
\usepackage{ytableau}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\begin{document}
\begin{example}
Let \Yvcentermath1$\tau=\Yboxdim{16pt}\young(7241,63,5)$ and $\upsilon=\Yboxdim{16pt}\young(1247,36,5)$ be tableaux. Then we have the 
following equation of tabloids:
\[\{\tau\}=\{\upsilon\}=\ytableausetup{tabloids,centertableaux}\ytableaushort{1247,36,5}.\]
\label{tabloid}
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

[image]